# Function command doesn't work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a datapack and a I have a function and when I call it normally within code or Minecraft it works fine and if I run the command `execute as @e[tag=robot] if block ~ ~-1 ~ air run function robot:simulate_gravity` in the code it doesn't work but inside Minecraft when I call it from the chat it does work.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function works, you must have an error with this part:

```
execute as @e[tag=robot] if block ~ ~-1 ~ air run
```

A multitude of problems could be causing this. In addition to the obvious (make sure there is an entity tagged `robot`, make sure the block under the robot is air, etc.), the most likely issue is that the function is not being ran `at` the robot. Instead, the `if block ~ ~-1 ~ air` check is run at the location the command was executed (at your player, or at a command block, whichever you are using).

Comment: Thank you very much! I forgot about that